# XCode Change Background Image with Orientation Change

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, background-image, device-orientation

I have an iPhone app made up of a single UIWebView that displays a website. I have set a background image to the UIWebView after it finishes loading within my `ViewController.m` file, as shown here:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     // Set UIWebView Background Image
     self->webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ui-background-portrait.png"]];
}
```

This is fine when the device is in Portrait orientation, but I would like to change the background image if the user switches the device orientation to landscape, and back to portrait if they switch again, etc.

I wrote the code below, but I'm not sure where to put it (as it needs to change the background image whenever they switch orientations; not just one time):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // Set UIWebView Background Image
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        // code for Portrait orientation  
        self->webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ui-background-portrait.png"]];
    }
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        // code for landscape orientation  
        self->webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ui-background-landscape.png"]];
    }
}
```

How can I accomplish this? And if you could give me code and indicate where to put it, that would be such a great help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override one of these methods in your view controller and put your code there.

[– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willRotateToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a)

[– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a)

[– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation%3a)

Put this code in your ViewController.m

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    // Set UIWebView Background Image
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        // code for Portrait orientation  
        self->webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ui-background-portrait.png"]];
    }
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        // code for landscape orientation  
        self->webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ui-background-landscape.png"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me some code? and where to put it? I've only been using Xcode and Objective C for about a week now... I catch on quickly though.

Comment: I figured it out (using the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation).Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)

Comment: I addes sample, but too late :)

Comment: Well maybe you can help with this instead: what are the dimensions for the background image in landscape orientation? I thought it would be 920x640 (for Retina) but when I use that size, the bottom of the image (in landscape orientation) seems to get cut off.

Comment: It's 960x640 but from these dimensions you need to substract height of status bar (20pt ->40px in Retina) and height of any Toolbar, NavigationBar, TabBar. So if you're landscape and your app shows status bar then it would be 960x600(in pixels)